# Neo4j Cypher: Merge duplicate nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have some duplicate nodes, all with the label Tag. What I mean with duplicates is that I have two nodes with the same name property, example:

```
{ name: writing, _id: 57ec2289a90f9a2deece7e6d},
{ name: writing, _id: 57db1da737f2564f1d5fc5a1},
{ name: writing }
```

The `_id` field is no longer used so in all effects these three nodes are the same, only that each of them have different relationships.

What I would like to do is:

1. Find all duplicate nodes (check)

   ```
   MATCH (n:Tag)
   WITH n.name AS name, COLLECT(n) AS nodelist, COUNT(*) AS count
   WHERE count > 1
   RETURN name, nodelist, count
   ```
2. Copy all relationships from the duplicate nodes into the first one
3. Delete all the duplicate nodes

Can this be achieved with cypher query? Or do I have to make a script in some programming language? (this is what I'm trying to avoid)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

APOC Procedures has some [graph refactoring procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_graph_refactoring) that can help. I think `apoc.refactor.mergeNodes()` ought to do the trick.

Be aware that in addition to transferring all relationships from the other nodes onto the first node of the list, it will also apply any labels and properties from the other nodes onto the first node. If that's not something you want to do, then you may have to collect incoming and outgoing relationships from the other nodes and use `apoc.refactor.to()` and `apoc.refactor.from()` instead.

Here's the query for merging nodes:

```
MATCH (n:Tag)
WITH n.name AS name, COLLECT(n) AS nodelist, COUNT(*) AS count
WHERE count > 1
CALL apoc.refactor.mergeNodes(nodelist) YIELD node
RETURN node
```

Comment: Wow I didn't about this apoc plugin. Very useful, thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to avoid the RETURN statement at the end of this query?
E.g if I only want to merge the nodes in the db without returning anything

Comment: Currently queries must end either with a RETURN, or with a write clause, such as SET, REMOVE, CREATE, DELETE, and MERGE. You can always return `count(*)` if you just want to keep the returned rows down to 1.

Answer (score 1):

The above cypher query didn't work on my Database `version 3.4.16`

What worked for me was:

```
MATCH (n:Tag)
WITH n.name AS name, COLLECT(n) AS nodelist, COUNT(*) AS count
WHERE count > 1
CALL apoc.refactor.mergeNodes(nodelist,{
  properties:"combine",
  mergeRels:true
})
YIELD node
RETURN node;
```